# React hookrouter multiple layouts

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-router, hookrouter

I want to use multiple layouts in React using hookrouter.

In normal react-router-dom I used routes within routes to achieve the multi-layout effect.

This is my existing react-router-dom code which I want to convert into hookrouter:

```
export default () =>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={[ Doctor_Login, Doctor_Panel , Reception_Login ,  Reception_Panel , Pharmacy_Login , "/"]}>
                <NavBar >
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={MainView}/>

                        <Route exact path={Doctor_Login}
                              render={(props) => <Login {...props} Type={"Doctor"} />}/>

                        <Route exact path={Doctor_Panel} component={DoctorPanel}/>

                        <Route exact path={Reception_Login}
                              render={(props) => <Login {...props} Type={"Reception"} />}/>

                        <Route exact path={Reception_Panel} component={ReceptionPanel}/>

                        <Route exact path={Pharmacy_Login}
                              render={(props) => <Login {...props} Type={"Pharmacy"} />}/>
                    </Switch>
                </NavBar>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={["/Test", Pharmacy_Panel , Pharmacy_Sell]}>
                <NavBarDrawer>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/Test" component={Tests}/>
                        <Route exact path={Pharmacy_Panel} component={PharmacyPanel}/>
                        <Route exact path={Pharmacy_Sell} component={SellPanel}/>
                    </Switch>
                </NavBarDrawer>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
```

Expected code in hookrouter

```
const routes = {
<Layout1>
    '/comp1': () => <Comp1 />,
</Layout1>

<layout2>
    '/comp2': () => <Comp2 />,
</layout2>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that based on nested routing section from docs:
https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter/blob/master/src-docs/pages/en/02_routing.md#nested-routing

in short you could have different layouts based on parent:

```
"app*": ()=> <AppLayout/>,
"pages*": ()=> <PagesLayout/>
```

where each layout component will have it's own routes